# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar body parser y una función que parece ser nativa de express?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estaba viendo que en muchos tutoriales utilizan body-parser y en otros utilizan funciones propias de express por decirlo de alguna forma.

Por ejemplo:

Con body-parser:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Usando solamente express:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
```

Quisiera saber lo que realmente hacen esas lineas y cuál es la diferencia entre utilizar body-parser ó express.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como podemos leer de la documentación de [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#readme):

> Node.js body parsing middleware.

En otras palabras es un *helper* para el *parseo* de peticiones HTTP. Existen otras herramientas que cumplen con el mismo fin, como:

- [body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body#readme)
- [co-body](https://www.npmjs.com/package/co-body#readme)

Y básicamente lo que hacen es facilitar la forma en la que puedes acceder al contenido de una petición HTTP según esté codificado.

- json
- form
- text
- etc

Las primeras versiones de express venían con `express.json()` entre muchas otras utilidades, mismas que decidieron mover a un paquete independiente a partir de la versión 4 (de hecho, si prestas atención al repositorio verás que son ellos los que mantienen body-parser). Fue entonces cuando pasó de ser `app.use(express.json())` a ser `app.use(bodyParser.json())`.

Sin embargo, en la versión [4.16.0](https://github.com/expressjs/express/releases/tag/4.16.0) se volvió a integrar dicha funcionalidad como parte de express, pues muchos usuarios lo preferían así, a tener que instalar un nuevo paquete para ello.

> Add `express.json` and `express.urlencoded` to parse bodies

Por lo que los dos métodos a los que te refieres, son lo mismo. Puedes usar body-parser:

```javascript
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Ó express:

```javascript
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
```

Ó incluso combinarlos

```javascript
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(express.json());
```

Puedes verlo desde el punto en que body-parser puede ser llevado fuera de express.